# How to add an image to TextView with UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I want to add an ability for a user to add an image to TextView when the button is pressed and the image is selected like it's done in Apple Notes app. I've tried some code, however with no luck...

**There's an example of how I expect it to look like:**
[image: Notes example]

**And that's my ViewController at the minute:**

[image: viewcontroller]

**The code so far:**

```
class PostViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var titleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var contentTextField: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var selectedImage: UIImage!

    @IBAction func chooseImageTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                       didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        self.selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)

        let textView = contentTextField
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: (textView?.attributedText)!)
        let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
        textAttachment.image = self.selectedImage

        let oldWidth = textAttachment.image!.size.width;
        let scaleFactor = oldWidth / ((textView?.frame.size.width)! - 10);
        textAttachment.image = UIImage(cgImage: textAttachment.image!.cgImage!, scale: scaleFactor, orientation: .up)
        let attrStringWithImage = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)
        attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: NSMakeRange(6, 1), with: attrStringWithImage)
        textView?.attributedText = attributedString;
        self.view.addSubview(textView!)
    }
```

Comment: what currently happens with this code?

Comment: I'm able to bring up Image Picker which allows me to choose the image from my camera roll. However, when I'm done choosing, it doesn't insert the picture in the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

add UITextViewDelegate

add textView.delegate = self in viewDidLoad()

class PostViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate , **UITextViewDelegate** {
}

Comment: You need to provide more context for this answer, as it does not really answer the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not clear how this answers the original question. Please provide an explanation of how your code solves OPs problem.

Comment: magi182, David Bowling now?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
So create action for the button.

```
        myTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "angular")!)
```

[image]

Now just give right parameters for your UIImage display, and write logic for button selection handling. Good luck!

In your case when you will get delegate image
info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
Just change background color as I changed.

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for inserting the image in-between the text as shown in the example and not setting it as a background image.